# Matplotlib adding overlay labels to an axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib I wish to know the cleanest and most robust means of *overlaying* labels onto an axis.  This is probably best demonstrated with an example:

[image: Labels]

While normal axis labels/ticks are placed every 5.00 units additional labels *without ticks* have been overlayed onto the axis (this can be seen at 1113.75 which partially covers 1114.00 and 1105.00 which is covered entirely).  The labels also have the same font and size as their normal, ticked, counterparts with the background (if any) going right up to the axis (as a tick mark would).

What is the simplest way of obtaining this effect in matplotlib?

**Edit**
Following on from @Ken's suggestion I have managed to obtain the effect *for an existing tick/label* by using `ax.yaxis.get_ticklines` and `ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels` to both remove the tick marker and change the background/font/zorder of a label.  However, I am unsure how best to add a new tick/label to an axis.

In other words I am looking for a function `add_tick(ax.yaxis, loc)` that adds a tick at location `loc` and returns the `tickline` and `ticklabel` objects for me to operate on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have been able to devise:

```
# main: axis; olocs: locations list; ocols: location colours
def overlay_labels(main, olocs, ocols):
    # Append the overlay labels as ticks
    main.yaxis.set_ticks(np.append(main.yaxis.get_ticklocs(), olocs))

    # Perform generic formatting to /all/ ticks
    # [...]

    labels  = reversed(main.yaxis.get_ticklabels())
    markers = reversed(main.yaxis.get_ticklines()[1::2]) # RHS ticks only
    glines  = reversed(main.yaxis.get_gridlines())
    rocols  = reversed(ocols)

    # Suitably format each overlay tick (colours and lines)
    for label,marker,grid,colour in izip(labels, markers, glines, rocols):
        label.set_color('white')
        label.set_backgroundcolor(colour)
        marker.set_visible(False)
        grid.set_visible(False)
```

It is not particularly elegant but does appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever tried to do that, but I think that the [Artist tutorial](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/artists.html) might be helpful for you. In particular, the last section has the following code:

```
for line in ax1.yaxis.get_ticklines():
    # line is a Line2D instance
    line.set_color('green')
    line.set_markersize(25)
    line.set_markeredgewidth(3)
```

I think that using something like `line.set_markersize(0)` might make the markers have size zero. The difficult part might be finding the ones that need that done. It is possible that the `line.xdata` or `line.ydata` arrays might contain enough information to isolate the ones you need. Of course, if you are manually adding the tick marks, it is possible that as you do that the instance gets returned, so you can just modify them as you create them.

Comment: I am unsure about how/when to add the extra ticks/labels (ideally I would like to do it as late as possible) and secondly how, when reducing the size of the tick, to have the label background expand to fill the space (as can be seen in the sample image).

Comment: @FreddieWitherden I think that I would try playing with the things and after you have tried a couple of things asking for specific help. Maybe give us some examples of some attempts that you have made.